# Highchart Hide/Remove Annotation buttons on export

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is there any property to remove/hide Annotation Button when a Chart is exported to PDF/PNG.
Refer to this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4s57pwns/3/)

```
exporting: {
                        buttons: {
                            contextButton: {
                                    menuItems: [
                                    {
                                        textKey: 'downloadPDF',
                                        onclick: function () {
                                            this.exportChart({
                                                type: 'application/pdf'
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

[image: Export with Annotations]

Comment: 100.5% looks like Russian elections...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `annotationsOptions.enabledButtons` to false in the exporting options.

```
 exporting: {
          chartOptions: {
            annotationsOptions: {
              enabledButtons: false
            }
          },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/4s57pwns/4/

Comment: Wow spot on, was not aware of these options. Can you share me a link where we can find all these properties.

Comment: The doc can be found on the website specific for a plugin - http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/17/Annotations
Doc for Highcharts in general (without any unofficial plugins) can be found [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)

Comment: Thank you @morganfree for sharing the links,  when i'm trying to deselect an annotation option it is first drawing the annotation and then deselecting it. How can I avoid redrawing of annotations while de-selecting it. [Sample Image](http://imgur.com/a/THKCr)

Comment: I am not sure what is happening based on the image. Please ask a new question with the code which will recreate the issue.